# How to merge different rows in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with *playid*, *userid*, *created*, and *stopped*. I want to merge certain rows by keeping the earliest *created* and the latest *stopped* within 120 minutes from the earliest *created*.

See the following table:

| playid | userid | created | stopped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:29:58.559858 | 2021-01-30 02:40:56.558436 |
| 2 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:41:24.023358 | 2021-01-30 02:55:24.112713 |
| 3 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:57:30.178579 | 2021-01-30 03:11:14.866678 |
| 4 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:11:41.098424 | 2021-01-30 03:22:50.155918 |
| 5 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:23:20.545288 | 2021-01-30 03:36:37.027486 |
| 6 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:46:10.237971 | 2021-01-30 03:59:17.526151 |
| 7 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:59:57.020326 | 2021-01-30 04:16:25.948311 |
| 8 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:26:28.968568 | 2021-01-30 04:30:11.863079 |
| 9 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:30:14.43786 | 2021-01-30 04:41:42.231915 |
| 10 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:43:17.669945 | 2021-01-30 04:45:10.443101 |
| 11 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:45:14.50346 | 2021-01-30 04:47:07.082114 |
| 12 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:47:10.334574 | 2021-01-30 04:49:30.96017 |
| 13 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:49:34.146011 | 2021-01-30 04:50:54.45988 |
| 14 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:50:57.948305 | 2021-01-30 05:11:01.246284 |
| 15 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:39:29.387396 | 2021-01-30 05:41:39.508654 |
| 16 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:41:44.524951 | 2021-01-30 05:43:38.231266 |
| 17 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:43:40.785809 | 2021-01-30 05:54:40.711381 |
| 18 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:55:10.851725 | 2021-01-30 05:58:24.262351 |
| 19 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:58:29.43821 | 2021-01-30 06:00:50.870644 |
| 20 | a01 | 2021-01-30 06:00:54.168696 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 21 | a01 | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.529666 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.349479 |
| 22 | a01 | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053136 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.532786 |
| 23 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547111 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.564802 |
| 24 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.248499 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.21787 |
| 25 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373145 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.099898 |
| 26 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.20448 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993751 |
| 27 | a01 | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.141051 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.464444 |

I want the query to give this table (see below). Please note that the next *created* is after the previous *stopped*, meaning the *created* with *playid* "8" is after *stopped* with *playid* "1":

| playid | userid | created | stopped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:29:58.559858 | 2021-01-30 04:16:25.948311 |
| 8 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:26:28.968568 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 21 | a01 | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.529666 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.532786 |
| 23 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547111 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.464444 |

Here is the query I have tried:

```
SELECT
    MIN(t1.playid) as playid,
    t1.userid,
    SAFE_CAST(t1.created AS DATETIME) as created,
    MAX(SAFE_CAST(t2.stopped AS DATETIME)) as stopped
FROM
    MyTable as t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MyTable as t2
        ON t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE
    DATETIME_DIFF(SAFE_CAST(t2.stopped AS DATETIME),SAFE_CAST(t1.created AS DATETIME),MINUTE) 
    < 120
GROUP BY
    t1.playid, t1.userid, t1.created
```

and querying the previous table using this query:

```
SELECT
    MIN(playid) AS playid,
    userid,
    MIN(created) AS created,
    stopped,
FROM
    MyTable2
GROUP BY
    userid
    stopped
```

This is the (wrong) table I get when I run the first query:

| playid | userid | created | stopped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:29:58.559858 | 2021-01-30 04:16:25.948311 |
| 2 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:41:24.023358 | 2021-01-30 04:30:11.863079 |
| 3 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:57:30.178579 | 2021-01-30 04:50:54.45988 |
| 4 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:11:41.098424 | 2021-01-30 05:11:01.246284 |
| 5 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:23:20.545288 | 2021-01-30 05:11:01.246284 |
| 6 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:46:10.237971 | 2021-01-30 05:43:38.231266 |
| 7 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:59:57.020326 | 2021-01-30 05:58:24.262351 |
| 8 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:26:28.968568 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 9 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:30:14.43786 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 10 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:43:17.669945 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 11 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:45:14.50346 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 12 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:47:10.334574 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 13 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:49:34.146011 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 14 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:50:57.948305 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 15 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:39:29.387396 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 16 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:41:44.524951 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 17 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:43:40.785809 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 18 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:55:10.851725 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 19 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:58:29.43821 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 20 | a01 | 2021-01-30 06:00:54.168696 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 21 | a01 | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.529666 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.532786 |
| 22 | a01 | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053136 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.532786 |
| 23 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547111 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.464444 |
| 24 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.248499 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.464444 |
| 25 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373145 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.464444 |
| 26 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.20448 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.464444 |
| 27 | a01 | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.141051 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.464444 |

The problem here is that the column *created* in the next row does not jump to the next *playid* with a *created* value which is larger/later than the *stopped* value of the current *playid*. Instead it just iterates through the table. Please see the tables above and use the *playid* column to make it easier to understand.

PS: I am very new to SQL. Please help me optimize this if this is very ineffective. Would be best to only have one query, of course.

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't the 3-rd row of the expected result be the row with playid=20, since 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 is within 120 minutes from 2021-01-30 04:26:28.968568 ?

Comment: You are right. I should have been more careful! It is now updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs loops/recursion which is not supported natively in BigQuery SQL. Try [user-defined functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions), but they are not very scalable:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION special_merge(x ARRAY<STRUCT<playid INT64, created_at TIMESTAMP, stopped TIMESTAMP>>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<playid INT64, created_at TIMESTAMP, stopped TIMESTAMP>>
LANGUAGE js
AS """
  var intervalStart = x[0].created_at;
  var intervalId = x[0].playid;
  var intervalEnd;
  var result = [];
  for (var row of x)
  {
    if (row.stopped - intervalStart > 120*60*1000 && intervalEnd) {
      result.push({playid: intervalId, created_at:intervalStart, stopped:intervalEnd});
      intervalStart = row.created_at;
      intervalId = row.playid
    }
    intervalEnd = row.stopped;
  }
  result.push({playid: intervalId, created_at:intervalStart, stopped:intervalEnd});
  return result;
""";

with mytable as (
  select 1 as playid, 'a01' as userid, timestamp '2021-01-30 02:29:58.559858' as created_at, timestamp '2021-01-30 02:40:56.558436' as stopped union all
  select 2, 'a01', timestamp '2021-01-30 02:41:24.023358', timestamp '2021-01-30 02:55:24.112713' union all
  select 7, 'a01', timestamp '2021-01-30 03:59:57.020326', timestamp '2021-01-30 04:16:25.948311' union all
  select 8, 'a01', timestamp '2021-01-30 04:26:28.968568', timestamp '2021-01-30 04:30:11.863079' union all
  select 20, 'a01', timestamp '2021-01-30 06:00:54.168696', timestamp '2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234' union all
  select 21, 'a01', timestamp '2021-01-30 14:41:01.529666', timestamp '2021-01-30 14:53:01.349479' union all
  select 22, 'a01', timestamp '2021-01-30 14:53:48.053136', timestamp '2021-01-30 15:05:09.532786' union all
  select 23, 'a01', timestamp '2021-01-31 15:11:08.547111', timestamp '2021-01-31 15:11:37.564802' union all
  select 27, 'a01', timestamp '2021-01-31 16:55:19.141051', timestamp '2021-01-31 17:03:43.464444'
)
select userid, m.*
from (
  select userid, special_merge(array_agg(STRUCT(playid, created_at, stopped) order by created_at)) as merged
  from mytable
  group by userid
), unnest(merged) as m
order by userid, m.playid
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for writing this. I am realising I should do this with Terraform and Python instead.